# How can I list all sections in the footer bar automatically?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation

I know how to customize the footer bar,

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsubsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    %\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertsubsubsection
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

How can I list all sections (subsections are not included) in the footer bar automatically, as shown in the following figure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility using a `beamercolorbox` of width equal to `0.7\paperwidth` and `\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.7\paperwidth}{}{}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.7\paperwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

A close-up to the footline:

[image]